# Extent parameter in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Is there any option like matplotlib's `extent` in Plotly? I have this code:

```
dx, dz = 100, 100
x = np.arange(0, 60000, dx)
z = np.arange(0, 30000, dz)

[zz, xx]= np.meshgrid(z, x, indexing='ij')

# Velocity model
vel = 1000 + 0.032 * zz

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
data = plt.imshow(vel, extent=(x[0]/1000, x[-1]/1000, z[-1]/1000, z[0]/1000),  cmap='seismic')
```

[image]

```
fig = px.imshow(vel, labels=dict(x="x[km]", y="z[km]", color="Velocity (m/s)"),
                color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
)

fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='x [km]', yaxis_title='z [km]', title='Raytrace')
```

[image]

As you can see, the ticks are not the same value.